# Swift 3 - Display alert controller asynchronously with long function running in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3.

The behavior I am trying to do is: the user clicks on a button, a spinning gear alert controller displays while it kicks off a long-running function.  Once that function is done executing, the spinning gear goes away and the view controller dismisses.

The code below kicks off the `doProcessing` function but doesn't display the spinning gear until about a second before the view dismisses.  So this isn't quite right.

```
func displaySpinningGear() {

    print("display spinning gear")
    // show the alert window box
    let activityAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Processing", message: "Please wait while the photo is being processed.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //create an activity indicator
    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: activityAlertController.view.bounds)
    indicator.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray

    //add the activity indicator as a subview of the alert controller's view
    activityAlertController.view.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // required otherwise if there buttons in the UIAlertController you will not be able to press them
    indicator.startAnimating()

    print("start animating")

    self.present(activityAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func onButtonClick() {
    self.displaySpinningGear()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.doProcessing() // long running function
    }

    if let viewController = presentingViewController {
        // This block will dismiss both current and a view controller presenting current
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // This block will dismiss only current view controller
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The code below kicks off the `doProcessing` function but the view dismisses immediately and I can tell from the console that my `doProcessing` function is still running.  This is not right either.

```
function onButtonClick() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("Processing")
        self.doProcessing() // run in background

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.displaySpinningGear()
        }
    }

    if let viewController = presentingViewController {
        // This block will dismiss both current and a view controller presenting current
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // This block will dismiss only current view controller
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How do I get the background function to kick off while displaying a spinning gear and dismiss the view and alert controller when the background function is done running (not before)?

**EDIT**

Tried moving the code to spin the gear outside the background block as per @Honey's suggestion in the comment but to no avail. The view immediately dismisses while the process function is still processing (I can tell through print statements).

```
func onButtonClick() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.displaySpinningGear()
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("Processing")
        self.doProcessing() // run in background
    }

    if let viewController = presentingViewController {
        // This block will dismiss both current and a view controller presenting current
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        // This block will dismiss only current view controller
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: in your 2nd solution: Try removing  `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.displaySpinningGear()
        }` to **outside** of the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. Additionally naming your function to `process` is better.

Comment: @Honey hm, that didn't seem to work.  See edit in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Callback from long running function so when it ends returns a value and catch it to disappear the alert.

Try it:

```
typealias DoProcessingCallback = (_ finished: Bool) -> Void

func onButtonClick() {
    self.displaySpinningGear()

    self.doProcessing(callback: { (finished) in

        if finished {
           // Here you DismissViewController
           // Here you DismissAlert
        }

    }) // long running function

}


func doProcessing(callback: DoProcessingCallback) {
    // YOUR LONG CODE....
    // When you know it already finished
    callback(true)
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that and it didn't work.  The behavior is that the button is clicked, no alert is displayed so it just sits there while the processing happens and about a split second before the processing is done, the alert shows and then the view dismisses.

Comment: Try calling de `doProcessing` callback function just after called `self.present(activityAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: To clarify: you mean move the `self.doProcessing(callback: .....` block into the `displaySpinningGear` function after the `self.present(activityAlertController...)` line?  I did that and the same behavior happens.

Comment: Yeah that was I mean... Are you sure the `doProcessing`function takes enough time? Probably this functions is taking less time that you think and the Alert doesn't have time to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried a bunch of different things and this is what worked:

```
activityView.alpha = 0.8
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "cropToProcessed", sender: self)
    })
})
```

Basically I set the alpha for activity indicator to 0.0 initially and when the button is pressed I set it to 0.8 and I set it back to 0.0 in viewWillDisappear and it works